# MSAL for iOS is unable to authenticate via the broker app (Authenticator)

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have followed the [Azure MSAL iOS integration Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios) and was able to authenticate myself via WebView (flow without the broker). When I try to run it via the broker, the broker is properly activated and then returns to the test app, but the result is the following error:

> Could not acquire token: Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)"
> UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=application did not receive response
> from broker., MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42700,
> MSALCorrelationIDKey=9A9A8D0C-BD53-4F72-8E94-D830E55012C5}

The relevant code is here:

```swift
applicationContext.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
    if let error = error { // the error is printed above
        self.updateLogging(text: "Could not acquire token: \(error)")
        return
}
```

[image]

Environment:

- My iOS version is `16.0`
- MSAL version is `1.2.3`
- Xcode: `14.0`
- Authenticator (broker): `6.5.98`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/1109), my app is using SceneDelegate alongside with the app delegate and I didn't [include logic](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc#swift-2) to notify MSAL about activation in the SceneDelegate. After adding it, the broken is able to successfully authenticate me:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        
        guard let urlContext = URLContexts.first else {
            return
        }
        
        let url = urlContext.url
        let sourceApp = urlContext.options.sourceApplication
        
        MSALPublicClientApplication.handleMSALResponse(url, sourceApplication: sourceApp)
    }
```